# backtesting options strategies in R

Tags: options, quant-trading-strategies, backtesting, r, delta-hedging

I would like to backtest an options strategy in R. I require the ability to delta hedge and rebalance to options in the portfolio at different frequencies (daily, monthly,etc.) What packages are the correct ones to use for this purpose? (I have seen the R Finance task view but there is a lot there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have a way to obtain hedge ratios and the like, your best available choice is probably [blotter](https://github.com/milktrader/blotter/wiki/The-Packages) (used to be just *quantstrat*).  You will find that it isn't necessarily oriented toward options.

Generally for options backtesting, pros end up making their own or buying commercial software.   There are tons of commercial providers, but I don't know anyone who has investigated the top candidates.

Comment: note though that since it's not on CRAN yet, i think that means the ensemble of packages is still in 'beta' mode.

Comment: blotter is very stable, but quantstrat is not. blotter is accounting infrastructure, it isn't oriented toward _any_ type of security. I'm currently working on adding options functionality to quantstrat.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be to use quantlib package to get the delta values and comply those to get a position delta. Then use rules based on delta values to hedge. Use discrete time adjustments or use delta bands.

Comment: yep, i got the deltas already. i really need something to do the delta hedging for me and pnl computations as those get slightly messy

Answer (score 0):

I just published a blog post on how to backtest options strategies with R:
[Backtesting Options Strategies with R](https://blog.ephorie.de/backtesting-options-strategies-with-r)

In the post, I provide the fully documented R code for your own experiments. The "trick" is to use the often publicly available *implied volatility* as a proxy for option prices (which are often hard to come by and/or very expensive).

For details please consult the post.